# not complete connection in a simple server/socket program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have 2 classes which are `GameServer` and `NetworkThread`. The program create a socket from somewhere else and then passes it to the `NetworkThread`'s constructor
I just want to have 2 clients and these 2 interact with each other.  First client's id in the `NetworkThread` constructor is 1 and the other one's is 2.
But when I start the 2nd client's connection it will never enter to the `NetworkThread` class.  Here is my code:

NetworkThread class:

```
public class NetworkThread implements Runnable, ActionListener {

    Socket newClient;
    String userName;
    int id;

    Scanner sc = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

    public NetworkThread(Socket newClient, String userName, int id) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.newClient = newClient;
        this.id = id;

        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(newClient.getOutputStream());
            sc = new Scanner(newClient.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        ConstructFrame();
        if (id == 1)
            changeTurnAsAGuesser();
        else
            startConnectionForSecondPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    private void changeTurnAsAGuesser() {   
        String word;
        String passing;

        word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Word",
                "input" + userName, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE).toUpperCase();
        passing = "~:";
            do {
                char x = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
                // after some works with ~> passing
                pw.println(passing);
                pw.flush();
            } while (checkWord(word, passing) == false);

                 //checkWord method returns a boolean
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    private void startConnectionForSecondPlayer() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    String taken = sc.nextLine();
                    jf.setTitle(taken);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

GameServer class:

```
public class GameServer {

    static int i = 0;
    ServerSocket gameServer = null;
    String userName;

    public GameServer(String username) {
        this.userName = username;
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    gameServer = new ServerSocket(4444);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        i++;
                        Socket newClient = gameServer.accept();
                        System.out.println(i);
                        Thread th = new Thread(new NetworkThread(newClient,
                                userName, i));
                        th.start();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

edit: I want to implement a Hangman game in which first client tell a word and the other one tries to guess that word but my main problem is that I can't start a successful connection!

Comment: Just some tip for future:
Do not use such way of dealing with clients, if you are planning to get a more than at least 100 connections for your server. Using separate thread for each client socket is memory consuming.

As well your architecture is not representing own structures. For example GameServer has field of name of user, what is a bit weird.
As well you increment 'i' each cycle, but if accepting will throw exception, then it will still apply increment.

Better read some articles about developing networking applications, for example: http://bit.ly/23Ke2h

Comment: I strongly disagree @Maksims.  Just about every web framework uses a thread per connection.  Java can create 1000s of threads with little overhead.  The alternative is vastly more complicated code with dubious performance characteristics.

Comment: You are ignoring all exceptions. Never do that. Log them or print their stack traces to the console. Please fix, re-run, and advise what happens. At present it could be anything.

Comment: I fixed that problem but unfortunately it's not an Exception problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see it.  You are doing all of the work in the constructor of your `NetworkThread` as opposed to the `run()` method.  In the constructor, when `id == 1`, that calls `changeTurnAsAGuesser` in the same thread that did the `accept`.  No other `accept` calls will be made until it returns.

What you need to do is remove the `if (id == 1)` code from the constructor and move it to the `run()` method which is called by the background thread:

```
public NetworkThread(Socket newClient, String userName, int id) {
    ...
    ConstructFrame();
    // don't do the interactive work in the constructor
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // do it in the background thread
    if (id == 1)
        changeTurnAsAGuesser();
    else
        startConnectionForSecondPlayer();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much  
but another problem by this way is NoLineFound Exception  
I don't Know what should I exactly do!  
Is there anywhere that I can send my complete codes?

Comment: You can post it on http://pastebin.com/ and provide the URL.  I'd recommend using the debugger and tracing your code.  That will help you figure things out.

Comment: I posted my codes here[link](http://pastebin.com/fs5J2PbT)thank you for your helps